# Fixing external image urls

Tags: images, htaccess

My images are currently externally linked to my blogger account. After importing everything through PowerPress, it imported all my images like this:

`<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;"><a href="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-YrjQLYBicjE/Wl19tTXO1mI/AAAAAAAAneY/ulQf9voxKGo0CTZFb4Xi96Lk0mFS2purwCLcBGAs/s1600/95DD6994-4A23-4B1C-A333-F5352B5A3B04.jpeg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" data-original-height="1200" data-original-width="1200" height="400" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-YrjQLYBicjE/Wl19tTXO1mI/AAAAAAAAneY/ulQf9voxKGo0CTZFb4Xi96Lk0mFS2purwCLcBGAs/s400/95DD6994-4A23-4B1C-A333-F5352B5A3B04.jpeg" width="400" /></a></div>`

Is there any kind of `.htaccess` code that will let me change the `/s400` to `/s1600` so that the right size image is being displayed on my site without having to edit each post individually?

Answer (score 5):

Since the request is sending to the blogspot server, no .htaccess wont wont.

You could [filter your post content](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) output:

```
add_filter('the_content', function($the_content) {
    return str_replace('/s400','/s1600',$the_content);
});
```

Or you could edit [modify the database](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Running_General_Queries)

```
global $wpdb;

$wpdb->query("UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET `post_content` = REPLACE(`post_content`,'/s400','/s1600');");
```

Or do it in mysql

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET `post_content` = REPLACE(`post_content`,'/s400','/s1600';
```

assuming `wp_posts` is your posts table.

Or you could use [wpcli](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/)

```
wp search-replace '/s400' '/s1600'
```

If you modify the database tho any of the methods, be sure to always backup the database before hand.

---

(Before anyone else dismisses my answer, please note that what I've provided would be an answer to your question, but it's a bandaid fix to the real problem: the images aren't in Wordpress and probably should be.

Comment: Yes, great answer but maybe he should better use the Import External Images plugin to import the images within WordPress. https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/import-external-images/

Comment: yes, absolutely. Didn't know that existed but thats exactly what's needed.

Comment: I actually did end up just moving all the images over manually. But this did work, just not for everything I needed.